# A be opposite to B

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

The [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/opposite) caustions against using "be opposite to" so that the following would be incorrect if "to" were included:

> *Do not say that one thing is ‘opposite **to**’ or ‘opposite of’ another. Say that one thing is opposite another: There’s a car park opposite the hotel*

However, the Merriam-Webster's Dictionary has the following examples:

> He lives opposite **to** me.

> Put one leg forward, and then lift the arm that is opposite **to** the forward leg.

Could anyone explain why "to" is used in one dictionary but not the other?

Comment: You give actual language from Merriam-Webster, but not what the other dictionary says. How in the world are we supposed to explain any difference when we don’t know **exactly** what the difference is.

Comment: @JeffMorrow See the edited post.

Comment: I couldn't find those definitions in Merriam-Webster. I did find them [here](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/opposite) in The Britannica Dictionary though.

Comment: Contemporary American speakers don't typically use "opposite" in this way. For example, we'd be far more likely to say, "He lives across from me." We use "opposite" plenty as an adjective or a noun - just not so often as an adverb. So it's actually kind of hard to have a strong feeling on the usage here.

Comment: @gotube The Britannica Dictionary was previously named the Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary.

Comment: I don't entirely agree with Longman. As a British English speaker I find _the people sitting opposite to us_ perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @KateBunting I'm surpriszed, given that Longman is a British publisher.

Comment: [This Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sitting+opposite+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) finds plenty of instances of 'sitting opposite to'.

Comment: @KateBunting Maybe Longman is limiting its restriction to the verb "be" and its variants.

Comment: You're missing the point that LODCE has ‘"not to say one thing is 'opposite to’ or ‘opposite of’ another"" when used as a **preposition** in **Br.E**. It gives examples with "to" when used as an adjective. [BtB](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_o&page=9f6h6X_fuaGE.html) says the same.

Comment: Sometimes both uses are possible. ['Opposite to' or 'opposite'](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/136940/12918) on ELU. Of interest as well: [Difference between Opposite and Opposite to](https://www.placementquestionpaper.in/difference-between-opposite-and-opposite-to/)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose opposite can be used with or without "to". Example sentences from [The Free Dictionary by FARLEX](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/opposite+to).

- Nevertheless, there she stood, anxiously fixing her eyes on one house in the row, nearly **opposite to** her -- the house she had looked for before entering the lodgings; the house inhabited at that moment by Noel Vanstone and Mrs.
- The knights, entering at either end of the lists in long procession, arranged themselves in a double file, precisely **opposite to** each other, the leader of each party being in the centre of the foremost rank, a post which he did not occupy until each had carefully marshalled the ranks of his party, and stationed every one in his place.

Apparently use of "across" has increased and that of "opposite" has decreased.

[image: Across vs Opposite]

"Opposite to" is less commonly used compared to "Opposite-any word"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At least for American English, the advice in Longman’s is wrong.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=across+from%2Copposite+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3

In fact, I would go so far as to say that using “opposite” as a preposition instead of “opposite to” in American **speech** sounds a bit pretentious or affected.

It is true, however, that when “opposite” is used as an adjective preceding the noun modified, “to” is not used in American English, *e.g*,

> the opposite opinion

> the opposite hand

Comment: It is possible that some instances of "opposite to" on Google n-grams are not about positions, so they may be irrelevant to the OP's issue. Also, Longman seems to limit its restriction to "be opposite" rather than verbs in general.

Comment: @Apollyon I have no doubt that you are correct. Ngram takes no account of context and so is a crude tool. My basic point is that “X is opposite to Y” is acceptable in American English. The Longman advice may or may not apply to British English, but it does not apply to American English as shown by both Ngram and a respected dictionary.